# Configure wifi on Dell Inspiron 11 3000

Tags: wireless, drivers, dell, inspiron

I just bought a dell Inspiron 300 (http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-11-3137/pd)

The strange thing is that I tried with elementary Freya beta 2 (elementaryos-unstable-amd64.20150208.iso) and it correctly detects it as:

```
$ lshw
...
*-network
    description: Wireless interface
    product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
    vendor: Broadcom Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    logical name: wlan0
    version: 01
    serial: 9c:ad:97:d6:fa:1b
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
```

Elementary freya is suppossed to be based on Ubuntu 14.04, and I tried with Ubuntu 14.04.02, 14.10 and also a 15.04 beta but the wireless network just won't show up.

Any idea

Comment: Please remove the `lshw` output and rather add the output of `sudo lshw -c network` instead, this will give the module and some other important info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go into system settings, software and updates, additional drivers should show the broadcom sta driver(aka bcmwl-kernel-source).  This driver should work for your wifi

Answer (score 0):

In this forum it says that the wifi wont work on live mode, but once installed it works out of the box

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2244361&p=13193735#post13193735